# Opción seleccionada por defecto

Tags: html, angularjs-2.0, select

Estoy llenando un select con angular 2 de la base de datos, entonces lo que necesito es que al momento que cargue la página principal aparezca como seleccionado el "Seleccione un elemento" que contiene el valor 0, 
¿Como puedo mandar por default el value para que al momento que carge la página venga seleccionado?

```
         <section class="validacion">
            <label class="label">{{'Empresa'}}</label>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select [(ngModel)]="model.IdEmpresa"   name="IdEmpresa" class="form-control">
              <option value="0" disabled>Seleccione un elemento</option>
              <option *ngFor="let empresa of empresaArray"   [value]="empresa.id" >{{empresa.nombre}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </section>
```

Comment: `selected` al primer `option` bastaría para que se seleccione por defecto.

Comment: No, no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Buenos dias, yo he hecho algo parecido pero en versiones anteriores a Angular 2, en la 1,6 para ser exacto, y lo hice de esta manera, no he estudiado versiones posteriores pero pues de pronto te pueda servir si es que entendi bien la pregunta.

```
              <div class="form-group" >
               <label class="control-label col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1" >Tipo Documento:</label>
               <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" >
                 <select name="" ng-model="tipoDocumento" class="form-control" id="selectDocumento" >
                   <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                   <option ng-repeat="documento in tableTipoDocumento" value="{{documento.id_tipoDocumento}}">{{documento.desc_tipo_documento}}</option>
                 </select>
               </div>
              {{tipoDocumento}}
             </div>
```

A lo que daría como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora quedaria el Select despues de seleccionar alguna opcion:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obteniendo el ID del elemento con el atributo Value

```
value="{{documento.id_tipoDocumento}}"
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda!